# android Mock location not working with locationservices.fusedlocationapi

Tags: android, location, google-api-client, fusedlocationproviderapi

After downloading and using 'Fake Gps' from google store, I thought of creating one for educational purposes.

I am using GoogleApiClient FusedLocationAPI for getting my current location and for creating a mock location. I am able to get my current location, but am unable to mock location.

```
public class GoogleApiClientGeoLocation implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    public GoogleApiClientGeoLocation(Context activity) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity, this, this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        ....
    }

    public void connect() {
        if (googleApiClient != null) {
           googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e("TAG","Location changed"+location.getLatitude() + ", "+ location.getLongitude());
    }

    private static final String PROVIDER = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;//"flp";
    private static final double LAT = 37.377166;
    private static final double LNG = -122.086966;
    private static final float ACCURACY = 3.0f;

    public Location createLocation(double lat, double lng, float accuracy) { //<-for testing purposes using a static lat,long
        // Create a new Location
        Location newLocation = new Location(PROVIDER);
        newLocation.setLatitude(LAT);
        newLocation.setLongitude(LNG);
        newLocation.setAltitude(1000);
        newLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());
        newLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        newLocation.setAccuracy(500);
        return newLocation;
    }

    public void startMock() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockMode(googleApiClient, true);
    }
    public void stopMock() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockMode(googleApiClient, false);
    }
    public void domock() {
        Location testLocation = createLocation(LAT, LNG, ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(_context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.setMockLocation(googleApiClient, testLocation);
            Log.e("TAG","Location Mocked");
        }else{
            Log.e("TAG","Can not Mock location");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class GoogleApiClientGeoLocation which handles all the functions.
Flow is initialization->connect->startmock->mock->stopmock->disconnect

If I do a connect(), locationchange() gives me current location, however when I startmock() and domock() locationchange() pauses and returns nothing, and when I stopmock() locationchange() starts giving me current location again.

I do get a log message saying 'location mocked'.

Is my 'PROVIDER' wrong?

I want to be able to create a mock location and be able to go to google map and see it pointing to mock location.

Answer (score 4):

It appears FusedLocationProvider is on a different clock then the System clock.  I.e. `elapsedRealTimeNanos` is different then `System.nanoTime`.  So the times you set by using the System clock will be off and I’m assuming the new Locations are considered stale and invalid.

To get a valid `elapsedRealTimeNanos` I add an offset to the `System.nanoTime()` each time I create a mock Location.   I calculate that  offset when I first connect to the googleApiClient:

```
Location current = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
nanoOffset = current.getElapsedRealtimeNanos() - System.nanoTime();
```

Then, the complete mock Location I create is as follows:

```
Location location = new Location("flp");  // indicates mock 
locationlocation.setLatitude(latLon.getLat());
location.setLongitude(latLon.getLon());
location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
location.setAccuracy(6f);
location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime() + nanoOffset);
```

Comment: It seems FusedLocation uses `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`, and you're calculating the offset between the two. Switching to `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` worked for me.